# When should I use named imports with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, react-hooks, es6-modules

I was wondering if I should use combination of default imports and named imports or stick with default import when working with complex module that involves React hooks.

Using `default and named imports` like below,

```js
import React, { Children, createRef, isValidElement, useCallback, useState } from 'react';

const [someBool, setBool] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {...}, []);
useCallback(() => {...}, []);

const childRefs = Children.map(props.children, child => createRef());

if (isValidElement(child)) {...}
```

or `default imports` only like below.

```js
import React from 'react';

const [someBool, setBool] = React.useState(true);
React.useEffect(() => {...}, []);
React.useCallback(() => {...}, []);

const childRefs = React.Children.map(props.children, child => React.createRef());

if (React.isValidElement(child)) {...}
```

I started with named imports and worked out great when there were simple hooks only, but it became ugly when traditional react functions like `React.Children.map` and `React.createRef` came in.

What are the best practices around module imports with React hooks?

Comment: Which one do you like more? Use that one.

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is if you use it more than once in a given file, used the named import.

Comment: I’ve been using named exports for hooks since their launch. For TS types though I tend to stick with `React.TypeName`. This creates an ugly boundary because `React.ReactNode` looks odd so as `memo(Component)` instead of `React.memo`. Using `React.stuff` everywhere could replace modality with a simple codebase-wide rule, which I potentially like. Perhaps, that's the way to go assuming that things can be tree-shaken in future similar to how it’s done for lodash via webpack and babel plugins? Keen to hear thoughts on this. DX feels potentially better with `React.stuff` despite extra verbosity.

Answer (score 3):

The decision is purely stylistic and what you choose won't have an effect on your application. That said, JavaScript style guides **do** exist and have enough usage that I'd feel comfortable referring to them to establish coding guidelines between your colleagues.

[**Airbnb's Stlye Guide**](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)

Airbnb doesn't have a rule on named vs. default imports. Their [React specific](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react) rules don't have a preference either. It's worth noting that their React examples use the default import.

[**Google's Style Guide**](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)

Google *kind of* approaches the topic in their [rules about exporting](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#es-module-exports).

> **3.4.2.1 Named vs default exports**
>
> Use named exports in all code. You can apply the `export` keyword to a declaration, or use the `export {name};` syntax.
>
> Do not use default exports. Importing modules must give a name to
> these values, which can lead to inconsistencies in naming across
> modules.

This rule requires that code must be exported with named exports, which would result in using named imports across the codebase. They don't have a rule about importing modules, but one could argue that using named imports for React would look more consistent with the rest of the codebase if you chose to follow this rule.

[**React Documentation**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook)

The "Hooks at a Glance" documentation page uses named imports. I think it's reasonable to assume most of the community will learn it with named imports and most React code will use named imports.

---

Personally, I use named imports for no particular reason. I just learned it that way and didn't question it. My codebase enforces a [style rule limiting the max line length](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len), and I suppose using named imports makes it less likely for me to violate that rule, which is at least a small win.